# difficulties with small lisp program for palindrome

Tags: lisp, clisp

Hi all I'm trying to write a lisp function using clisp v2.47 which takes a word and returns true if it is a palindrome otherwise it will return false.  By the way whats worth mentioning is that I'm new to lisp so i don't have experience in writing lisp code.

Here is my code:

```
(defun palindrome( L )   
    (cond 
        ((equal L '()) T  )    
        ((equal (car (L)) (last ( L ))) 
            (palindrome (cdr (reverse (cdr (L))))))
        (t nil)))
```

When I paste it into clisp it is fine but when i come to run it i get this error that i don't know how to fix:

```
[2]> (setq M '(bob))
(BOB)

[3]> (palindrome M)

*** - EVAL: undefined function L
The following restarts are available:
USE-VALUE      :R1      Input a value to be used instead of (FDEFINITION 'L).
RETRY          :R2      Retry
STORE-VALUE    :R3      Input a new value for (FDEFINITION 'L).
ABORT          :R4      Abort main loop
Break 1 [4]>
```

Any help would be most appreciated as I'm really in a hurry to finish this program.

Thanks all

Comment: You may want to look at the documentation for [LAST](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_last.htm) (particularly the examples).  I don't think it does what you think it does.

Answer (score 4):

The call `(last ( L ))` does not compute the last element of the list `L`. It calls the function named `L` without any arguments, expects to get a list as a returned value, and calculates the last *cell* of that list. `(car (last L))` will calculate the last element of a list.

In Lisp, parentheses are not for grouping your code statements. They signify functional application instead.

```
(a b c d)
```

means, "call a function `a` with arguments `b, c, d`".

```
(a)
```

means, "call a function `a`".

So, your code does not define any function named `L`. It uses a parameter named `L`, but in Common LISP function names and value names are two different namespaces.

```
[11]>
(defun palindrome( L )
    (cond
        ((null L) T  )
        ((equal (car L) (car (last L)))
            (palindrome (cdr (reverse (cdr L)))))))
PALINDROME
[12]> (palindrome '(bob))
T
```

***edit:*** Following on the nicest idea by *wvxvw*, here's a better code for it, which doesn't traverse the list so much:

```
(defun palindrome (x) 
  (do ((x x (cdr x)) 
       (y x (cddr y)) 
       (z () (cons (car x) z)))
      ((null (cdr y)) 
       (equal z (if y (cdr x) x)))))
```

Answer (score 3):

Whatever you put in the first element of a list gets treated as a function when the list is evaluated. Try removing some excess parens:

```
(defun palindrome( L )   
    (cond 
        ((equal L '()) T  ) 
        ((equal (car L) (last L)) 
            (palindrome (cdr (reverse (cdr L)))))
        nil))
```

Comment: thanks for the help I reviewed my code again and tried to remove as many parenthesis as possible and had the same problem. I suspected that the problem is with the following line (palindrome (cdr (reverse (cdr L))))) so I removed that case and left the two others ((equal L '()) T  ) and (T nil) and I got the same error again so it is something else but I can't figure it out

Comment: your clause NIL should be (NIL). Is what my CLISP tells me. :)

Comment: you missed (and I did too, at first) that (last L) returns last *cell* of a list, not last *element*.

Comment: @nathan hughe,@will ness hey there I finally got the program to work the problem was with the call to the function last which was returning a list with the last element in it.  In addition to that there was another problem which is that when I come to enter the input to run the program I have to enter it as follows >palindrome('(b o b) ) with spaces between every letter otherwise the result is always true.  Here is a example to show u what i mean  >palindrome('(bob) )  is always true.  Anyway I must say it was actually rather fun to finally solve the problem and thanks to u all for ur help.

Comment: Also `(palindrome (coerce "redivider" 'list))` when using strings

Comment: @nerd that what *cell* is, a *cons* cell is a list (might be dotted list too). To access its contents, we use `car`, as shown in my answer.

Comment: hi, something went wrong with your last edit, the text didn't change at all.

Answer (score 1):

That is not really a good algo you are using. You will reverse and go to the last element of the list too many times (both `reverse` and `last` have O(n) speed). You will call reverse n/2 times and last n/2 times, making overall function time O(n^2). Below is an algo that does the same

```
(defun palindrome-p (x)
  (let ((half-length (floor (/ (length x) 2))))
    (do ((i x (cdr x))
         (j 0 (1+ j)))
        (nil)
      (when (= j half-length)
        (labels ((compare (head tail)
                   (cond
                     ((or (null head) (null tail)) t)
                     ((not (equal (car head) (car tail))) nil)
                     (t (compare (cdr head) (cdr tail))))))
          (return (compare x (reverse i))))))))
```

but in O(2n+n/2) time as it's worst case. I know, it's not very "scientific" to put a constant next to n here, but it is to illustrate that while the time is linear, you will need to visit all nodes twice - first time for calculating the length and second time when comparing lists. the n/2 is from calling reverse before you compare.

Note that there is a very straight-forward naive palindrome function:

```
(defun naive-palindrome-p (x)
  (equal x (reverse x)))
```

But if we agree on my anti-scientific O(), then this one is O(2n) (once we look through the whole list to reverse it, the second time we look through the whole list to compare results. This function will perform better then the first one in it's worst case, but the first will perform better in it's best case. Also, it's not uncommon for Lisp implementations to store the length of the list instead of calculating it, which may give you almost half speed reduction in the first function.

Comment: nice idea! `(defun palindrome (x) (do ((x x (cdr x)) (y x (cddr y)) (z () (cons (car x) z))) ((null (cdr y)) (equal z (if y (cdr x) x)))))`

Comment: I've added this version based on your idea to my answer, with attribution to you. hope it's ok. I felt it would be too bad to leave it buried in the comments. should I rollback?

Answer (score 0):

(defun palindrome( L )

(  cond

((equal L '()) T )

((equal (car L) (car(last L))) (palindrome (cdr (reverse (cdr L)))))

(T NIL)

)

)

Comment: Hi all, sorry that I didn't post the final answer to my question because I'm new to this site.  Therefore according to site regulations a new user isn't allowed to post a answer until after 8 hours or something like that.  The above code is the final code working without any problems